# Limiting distribution of distance of points inside a circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$n$ points are uniformly distributed inside a circle of radius $\sqrt{n}.$ Let $T_n$ be the distance from the center of the circle to the closest point. I want to find the limiting distribution of $T_n.$

Let $(X,Y)$ be a coordinate of a point chosen. Then, I know that the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{\pi n}, & x^2 + y^2 \leq n \\
0, & x^2 + y^2 > n.
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Picking the center of the circle to be the origin, I think that I can let $T_n = \sqrt{X_n ^2 + Y_n ^2 }$ but I am not sure where to go from here.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one random point in the circle of radius $\sqrt{n}$, the distance $S$ to the center has CDF
$$P(S \le s) = \frac{s^2}{n}.$$
Since $T_n$ is the minimum of $n$ independent copies of $S$, we have
$$P(T_n > t) = P(S > t)^n = (1 - t^2/n)^n.$$
Take the limit of the last quantity to reveal the tail probability $P(T_\infty > t)$ of the limiting distribution $T_\infty$.

Comment: giving... $e^{-t^2}$ (not evident to see, if one is not familiar with this kind of limit)